# Printer prints contents only on half of the A4 page

Tags: printing, printer, brother-printer

**Brother MFC-J44200DW

Windows 10

Wlan connection**


I have issues with my printer. Every time I try to print an A4 page from word or a pdf my printer prints it in on half the size of the A4 page. It looks like two pages per sheet is selected but if I have two pages in word both will be printed on a seperate sheet, on the rigth half and with the left side empty.
 Everything is set to: **Papersize A4, portrait, one page per sheet**.
I checked the word settings, the printer settings and the settings on the printer.
I also have reseted the printer, removed it and added it again to the pc but I just can't find out why it does what it does. If I create an A4 document in word and send it to my phone I can print it correctly. So the settings on the printer and in word have to be correct.
How it looks in word:
[image]
How it looks printed:
[image]
Did anyone have similar experiences with brother printers or knows of any hidden windows printer settings that I am overlooking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is happening from all applications, I'm guessing the driver is corrupt. To fix that, I would reinstall the driver, as follows.

Go to Devices & Printers, and delete the printer. From Settings, uninstall any Brother software. Next, go back to Devices & Printers and click on any other printer. Now select "Print server properties" from the menu that appears at the top, click the Drivers tab and remove all instances of the printer.

Then reinstall from a freshly downloaded driver.

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same problem, and it drove me crazy since all the settings were right. At least I thought they were.  BUT the issue is that the drivers installed by Windows (and which seem to indicate the printer was actually installed correctly) are generic.

Therefore one should go to 'Printer properties' >> Advanced and make sure you see listed there the driver for your printer (manufacturer and type).

If not (as it was my case), click on 'new driver', wait for Windows to update the drivers list, and when that's done (it takes a while!) select the manufacturer and the type of your printer. Install it, and you're good to go.

One would have expected a bit more from the newest Windows, especially since we're in 2024!! And especially since it is very confusing at first, as all seems to be in order except it was not printing properly.